# Stop object with raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

So i have simple object (camera) and i do not wanna let her go through wall. What i have done is simple raycast coding with this:

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(myCamera.transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, distanceFromMesh))
{
    currPos.y = hit.point.y + distanceFromMesh;
}
if (Physics.Raycast(myCamera.transform.position, Vector3.up, out hit, distanceFromMesh))
{
    currPos.y = hit.point.y - distanceFromMesh;
}
if (Physics.Raycast(myCamera.transform.position, Vector3.left, out hit, distanceFromMesh))
{
    currPos.x = hit.point.x - distanceFromMesh;
}
if (Physics.Raycast(myCamera.transform.position, Vector3.right, out hit, distanceFromMesh))
{
    currPos.x = hit.point.x + distanceFromMesh;
}
```

This works good when i am moving camera slowly to the wall (like normal person), but when i SLAM it to the wall, it get's through and get's stuck inside (because of raycast check for other side movement.

What can i do to stop that going throug. My `distanceFromMesh = 0.2f`

Comment: Configuration solution: https://answers.unity.com/questions/34444/high-speed-object-collisionhow-to-avoid-pass-throu.html

Comment: And here's a raycast solution: https://answers.unity.com/questions/55179/cheapest-way-to-catch-collisions-on-very-fast-movi.html?childToView=55185#answer-55185

Comment: You have asked the same question before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206363/stop-camera-from-moving-through-objects

Comment: Totally different questions.

Comment: Use cinemachine, it is free. It can help you get good camera movements with damping and everyting. Asset store link-https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/cinemachine-79898

Comment: Is your raycast running in Update loop or in Fixed update?

Comment: Sorry to bother you i know why it is not working. It is because in newer versions  to collison detect you cannnot move object with `transform.pos` but `addVelocity` or something similar..

Comment: If you've solved it, post it as an answer so that future viewers can fix the problem.

Comment: It is still not solved (yes to some part) but i will post answer after i finish it all